# Setting a pdf field value with AbcPdf 10 creates a placeholder with the wrong value

Tags: abcpdf

I am setting values of fields in an abcpdf 10 document, then returning it as a file to the browser.  But it is creating some sort of placeholder, even though the true value is there.  The first image is how the field looks originally with the wrong value; the second is when the field is clicked and has the right value.

[PDF without the field clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgIFo.png)

[PDF with the field clicked and correct value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0ULk.png)

These images are from Chrome.  The document renders correctly in Acrobat.

Comment: My hunch is that this is an issue with Chrome's PDF rendering engine. However, first I would recommend trying the [latest version of ABCpdf (11.3)](https://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-download.aspx).  This will be backward compatible with version 10. You'll also receive free technical support with the trial

Comment: Thanks.  I will try the latest version.

Comment: Did that fix your issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  Yes, upgrading fixed it.